# How to add button instead of error status and success message in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been created subscribe button using php,

Html:

```
 <div id="newsletterform">
                <h2>Get Email Update</h2>
                <form action="send.php" method="post" id="newsletter" name="newsletter">
                    <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="signup-button" id="signup-button">
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </form>
                <div id="response"></div>
            </div>
```

Now i had been found some click effect of buttons, here is the link, http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/

In the above, 7th section[green color section], it has two submit form buttons.

One for success and one for error, so i need to use them in my subscribe form, i mean move to my send.php.

So when i click subscribe button without enter email, it shows button says, "error" instead, notification.

May i know, is it possible to achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just add `required` to the `<input>`? You won't need to check for it being empty on the client side.

Comment: can you provide explanation please @AfaanBilal: thanks

Comment: Replace `<input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />` with `<input type="email" required name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />`.

Comment: this is what i don't need.. i need to use button effects instead message status.

Comment: Check if my answer did what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

there is an easy way to ding so you place both two button and give error button to css `display:none;` 
as in jquery

```
else {
            $status = "error";
            $message = "An error occurred, please try again";
            $('.button-error').show();
            $('.button-success').hide();
        }
```

in this way you can achieve what you want

Comment: i just give a example css class you can change it as your requirement

Comment: then you can download it and add to your file  make sure it cannot effect to your another js

Answer (score 1):

Download and place `component.css` in `css` folder, then add this to `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
```

HTML :

```
     <div id="newsletterform">
            <h2>Get Email Update</h2>
            <form method="post" id="newsletter" name="newsletter">
                <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="signup-button" id="signup-button" class="btn btn-7 btn-7h icon-envelope">
                <span class="arrow"></span>
            </form>
            <div id="response">
            <?php if (isset($_POST['signup-button']) { ?>
                <span color="<?=($status=='success')?'green':'red';?>"><?=$message;?></span>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And place just before closing `</body>`:

```
<?php if ($status == "error") { ?>
<script>
    document.getElementById('signup-button').className = "btn btn-7 btn-7h icon-envelope btn-error";
    setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('signup-button').className = "btn btn-7 btn-7h icon-envelope";
    }, 1000);
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Put the following at the top of your `footer.php` or `index.php` (in which you `include()` the `footer.php`)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-button'])) {
    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
        if (empty($email)) {
            $status = "error";
            $message = "The email address field must not be blank";
        } else if (!preg_match('/^[^0-9][A-z0-9._%+-]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/', $email)) {
            $status = "error";
            $message = "You must fill the field with a valid email address";
        } else {
            $existingSignup = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM signups WHERE signup_email_address='$email'");
            $existingSignup->execute();
            $data_exists = ($existingSignup->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;
            if (!$data_exists) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date) VALUES (:email, :datetime)";
                $q = $db->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute(
                    array(
                        ':email' => $email,
                        ':datetime' => $datetime
                ));
                if ($q) {
                    $status = "success";
                    $message = "You have been successfully subscribed";
                } else {
                    $status = "error";
                    $message = "An error occurred, please try again";
                }
            } else {
                $status = "error";
                $message = "This email is already subscribed";
            }
        }
        $data = array(
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message
        );

        echo json_encode($data);

        $db = null;
    }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Also have a look here :

http://jsfiddle.net/8ft0ye6k/3/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ofcourse you need send.php, I am assuming you are somehow passing the `$error` back to the html page somehow. Why don't you place the php code in the same file as your html, then it'd work automatically.

Comment: then may i know, what about classie.js and default.css?

Comment: You don't need them. They were specific for that demo.

Comment: but still now i didn't get, it stays same. @Afaan Bilal: thanks

Comment: Set the action attribute of the form to "" and place your php code on top of the same file as your html (make sure it ends in .php). Wrap your php code in if(isset()) statement. Then it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72108/discussion-between-rish-and-afaan-bilal).

Comment: is it possible to give solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72126/discussion-between-afaan-bilal-and-rish).

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b9y5bunp/)

Add this css and js this should works

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/css/default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/css/component.css" />
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

<script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/js/classie.js"></script>



 $status = "<button class="btn btn-1 btn-1a">Button</button>";
 $message = "An error occurred, please try again";

 $status = "<button class="btn btn-1 btn-1a">Button</button>";
 $message = "This email is already subscribed";
```

Comment: here is updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/b9y5bunp/3/ .. so how to use this for my existing subscribe form? thanks

Comment: include your javascript code in main page where u call ajax function @rish got it ?